# How to stack the graphs in such a way that the share a common scale along x-axis

Tags: matplotlib

The following code is for generating the 3 subplots. And on all the 3 subplots scale is mentioned. I want to stack them in such a way that x-axis and y-axis scale appear once like this. Can I get this plot with plt.subplot() or fig.add_axes is compulsory for this? I actually want to do this with subplots because in fig.add_subplot I havve to specify the width and height of each plot that I don't want.

[image]

```
`fig,axes = plt.figure(nrow=3, ncolmn=1)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(313)
ind1 =[1,2,3]
ind2 = [4,5,6]
for i in range(len(3)):
    data1=np.load(..)
    data2=np.load(..)
    axes[i].plot(data1, data2)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using `subplots_adjust` where you put the space between two plots to 0 using `hspace`. Also, use `sharex=True` to have a shared x-axis

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1,sharex=True)
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.ravel()): # or axes.flatten() or axes.flat
    ax.plot(x, y, label='File %d' %i)
    ax.legend()
fig.text(0.5, 0.01, 'X-label', ha='center')
fig.text(0.01, 0.5, 'Y-label', va='center', rotation='vertical')  
plt.tight_layout() # To get a better spacing between the subplots
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.0)
```

[image]